# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void CreateUse(List<Ent_Req__c>) from the type Usrcreation_controller

Tags: apex, trigger, create-records

I am trying to create a user record based on other record getting created, I added all the code in apex class and I am trying  to call apex code method in my trigger. I am getting incorrect signature error.

my apex class code signature is
`public static void CreateUser(List<User> ur)`

and I am calling this method in my trigger like
`Usercreation_controller.CreateUser (Trigger.new);`

I tried to pass arguments as ur. I am able to save the code, but the user record is not getting created

Comment: Can you add your relevant code here? In its current form you have discrepancies in the title and the contents so its not very clear where the issue is. Providing some details will help anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question title, you are trying to access `CreateUse(...)` instead of `CreateUser(...)` mentioned in your apex class.

But it would be kind of you to add code in the description.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information available, here are the few things you need to correct

- From the question's title, it says that you are calling `CreateUse` whereas the method name is `CreateUser`. **Anyhow, I hope this is just a typo as it wouldn't have compiled and wouldn't have allowed you to save the code.**
- From the question's title, it says that you are passing `List<Ent_Req__c>` to `CreateUser` method whereas you should pass `List<User>`. Assuming that you have a trigger on `Ent_Req__c` object, so `Trigger.New` will contain the `List<Ent_Req__c>` and not `List<User>` which is what is expected for `CreateUser` method.

So, you will have to perform either of the below two options

- Change your methods signature to accept `List<Ent_Req__c>` and construct `List<User>` that needs to be inserted and perform DML in your method.
- Construct the `List<User>` from `List<Ent_Req__c>` in your trigger and then pass `List<User>` to `CreateUser` method of your class to perform DML or any other logic that needs to be implemented.